# Update addressee values for all contacts after modifying Addressee Type Options

Tags: tokens

I have updated the tokens in my *Addressee Type Options* (at **Administer > Communications > Addressee Formats**), and now CiviCRM is now generating my desired addressee values each time I save contacts.

This is great, going forward.

But how can I update the addressee values for *all* the contacts in my database, without having to go edit/save them all one-by-one?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`update_greeting` scheduled job](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/#job_update_greeting).

1. Go to **Administer > System Settings > Scheduled Jobs**
2. Click **Add New Scheduled Job**, and enter the following values.

   - "Name": "Force Update Addressee Values"
   - "Description": (blank)
   - "Run frequency": "Every time cron job is run"
   - "API call": select "Job", and enter "update_greeting" in the text field
   - "Command parameters":

     ```
     ct=Individual,Household,Organization
     gt=addressee
     force=1
     ```
   - "Scheduled Run Date": (blank)
   - **Uncheck** "Is this Scheduled Job active?"

     (This is **important** because you don't want your scheduled job to run automatically.)
3. Click **Save**.
4. Find your scheduled job in the list of all jobs, and click **More > Execute Now**
5. Find your scheduled job in the list of all jobs, and click **View Job Log**. Verify that you see "Success" in the log. Troubleshoot any errors.

Comment: Sean, this could also be done from the API Explrorer, right?