# Is there a way to update the contact.addressee field in batches?

Tags: contacts, tokens, scheduled-job

I have about 50,000 contacts to update and I have a scheduled update greeting job set up (based on this post [Update addressee values for all contacts after modifying Addressee Type Options](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24321/update-addressee-values-for-all-contacts-after-modifying-addressee-type-options) - thanks Sean!)

If I run the scheduled job, it never completes (it hits a max execution time limit.) I did find that I can limit the number of contacts (to say 2500) with the limit parameter, and the job will complete. But my assumption is that if I run the job again it just updates my first 2500 contacts over again. Is that a correct assumption?

Is there another way I can update the contact.addressee token in batches to avoid hitting the max execution time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several solutions.  I'll go from least to most work - though the "least work" solutions generally need a level of expertise that the "most work" solutions don't.

- You can edit your `max_execution_time` in `php.ini`.
- The default execution time when running from the command line is unlimited.  So you could run `cv api Job.update_greeting` or the equivalent using `drush` or `wp-cli` if you don't have `cv` installed.
- Greetings are updated whenever a record is updated.  An easy way to batch update records is to import a list of all the contact IDs you want to update with no other info.  This will force an update and thus a greeting update.
- You can delete all your addressee values that need updating (or all of them!) through MySQL/phpMyAdmin, then use "Update Greetings" with a limit of 2500 and set `force` equal to 0.  With `force` equal to zero, only contacts without addressees will be updated, so you won't do the same 2500 every time.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed listing. The second option is appealing - I don't have cv installed but am running on Drupal. Do I need anything extra installed to use the Drush method?

Comment: Nope - you might want to confirm that PHP has an unlimited `max_execution_time` on command-line, but assuming so, the command is just `drush civicrm api Job.update_greeting`.

Comment: We opted to try the drush option first - and it worked!! Some random tidbits for anyone that might happen across this post. I had to run the drush command as apache, it also required me to add the ct and gt parameters. My final command was(after telling it to run as apache) /path/to/drush civicrm-api Job.update_greeting ct=Individual gt=addressee force=1